# Get video frames programmatically

Tags: python, video-streaming, obs

I'm trying to write an `obspython` script, that would get frames from the source, change them and output them back. Right now I managed to get the needed source with

```
source = obs.obs_get_source_by_name("Screen")
```

but trying to get a frame just outputs None

```
print(obs.obs_source_get_frame(source))
```

Is there a way to capture and edit frames with OBS scripts? If not in Python, maybe I can write a script in C that will interact with Python?